# How to display value of specific adress in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb, nasm

Now I have learnt a little bit of assembler (using NASM) I want to use gdb to debug my programs.

Is there a option to see the value at a specific adress or a specific field?

For example:

```
variable resd 2
```

I reserved 2*4 Bytes of memory, which is available under the marker variable.
How can I debug the value of the address `[variable+4]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x can be used for displaying memory at an address, watch could be used for adding a variable to the watch-list.